# Cannot include a prepopulated sqlitedatabase in android project

Tags: android, sqlite

I have looked at the posts about including a prepopulated sqlite database, but i am still getting an error. Here is my Database Helper class:

```
public class MyDBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static MyDBHelper mInstance = null;
private static final int DB_VERSION = 5;
private static final String DB_NAME = "database.sqlite";
static final String TABLE_NAME = "PRODUCTS";
private final Context mContext;
private static SQLiteDatabase myWritableDb;
private static final String DATABASE_PATH = "/data/data/com.example.barcodescanner/databases/";

public static MyDBHelper getInstance(Context ctx) {
    if (mInstance == null) {
        mInstance = new MyDBHelper(ctx.getApplicationContext());
    }
    return mInstance;
}

private MyDBHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
    this.mContext = context;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {

}

public void createDatabase() throws IOException {
    createDB();
}

private void createDB() throws IOException {

    boolean dbExist = DBExists();
    if (!dbExist) {
        this.getReadableDatabase();
        copyDBFromResource();
    }

}

private boolean DBExists() {
    File dbFile = new File(DATABASE_PATH + DB_NAME);
    return dbFile.exists();
}

private void copyDBFromResource() throws IOException {
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    OutputStream outStream = null;
    String dbFilePath = DATABASE_PATH + DB_NAME;

    try {
        inputStream = mContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
        outStream = new FileOutputStream(dbFilePath);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            outStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        outStream.flush();
        outStream.close();
        inputStream.close();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
}


@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int oldVersion,
        int newVersion) {
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);
}


}
```

I create the database like the following:

```
public MyDBHelper helper = MyDBHelper.getInstance(this);        
helper.createDatabase();
```

The problem is, in copyDBFromResource function, in the following line:

```
outStream = new FileOutputStream(dbFilePath);
```

i get an exception saying that

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/com.example.barcodescanner/databases/database.sqlite: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

What am i doing wrong? The package name in my DATABASE_PATH variable is the package name in which MainActivity stays. Is that wrong? Can anyone help me to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: What if you **get rid** of DATABASE_PATH? It works, for me.

Comment: Please use `SQLiteAssetHelper` for packaging a database for distribution with your app: https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to access a DB from another app, you should know that apps can access only their own files from the internal memory, so from your app you can not access the DB from another app. However, you can access files of other apps if they are located on the "external" storage:

[Android Training: Saving Files](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html)

> Internal storage:
>
> - It's always available.
> - Files saved here are accessible by only your app by default.
> - When the user uninstalls your app, the system removes all your app's files from internal storage.

Update:

As mentioned in a comment above, you don't need to provide the path to the app's DB (and you don't have to access the file directly), you need to provide only the DB name in the constructor of your MyDBHelper class (which you did). I suggest to have a look [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html), in my opinion, it is explained well how to work with databases in Android .

Answer (score 0):

- Never hardcore paths for application-private file
- use context.getPackageName() whenever you need to include a package name

Database path should be.

```
final File databaseFile = context.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME);
```